# LED driver/analog adjustable constant current source with constant output without PWM switching?

Tags: analog, boost, constant-current, dimming

I am using 3 halogen lights with 5V/0.5A each controlled by a constant current source (or basically "LED driver") because of light accuracy. Right now I am using the PT4115 (step down led driver) for each light bulb, but this one is also getting really hot. Input voltage is 12V.  For another revision, I was planing to run all light bulbs (those 7.5W total) with only one IC because of limited PCB space. I was looking around the whole last day but couldn't really find what I was looking for. There are many step up led drivers, but those are really made to drive led's at true colour with PWM dimming instead of analog diming.

Functional schematic:

[image: Text]

For example, the Analog Devices led driver can be run on PWM (or frequency set) mode with additional analog diming, but not on analog diming alone, example: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/80421fb.pdf The RT-pin doesnt go down to 0 Hz, but can be only minimised to 250 kHz, which is not suitable, since I need constant lighting without PWM flimmering.

Does some IC series I am looking for even exist or is there any possible solution for turning an PWM input into a constant analog control input with an additional circuit, so that the light is always on without any switching?

Comment: "Analog dimming" just means changing the drive current, which any Buck or Boost LED driver can do.  The RT pin on that driver is the switching frequency of the Buck/Boost converter.  It has nothing do with PWM or dimming.  To change the current ("dimming") you would use the CTL pin to set a different drive current.

Comment: Ah I mistook the switching frequency of the regulator itself with the frequency of dimming. But still, am I right that although on the datasheet linked in the question on page 6 "LED Current vs CTL Voltage" there is a linear correlation , analog dimming is still limited to 10 steps (or 10:1) or is it linear with non-discrete steps and I am wrong on that one?

Comment: You're limited to current in that range, which is approximately a 10-fold difference. That is an expensive converter designed for high dynamic range PWM dimming. If you don't want that consider a different converter.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I know, this is not the website for discussions, but could you point out to a step up converter with up to ~0.7-1A output current and analog dimming functionality? Everything I found was really the same with special PWM dimming or has a bad thermal resistance for those 7.5W output

Comment: @Dakalaom +1 just because I learned a new word -- flimmering!

Comment: Would something like an lm3409 work? If not, could probably go through the parametric search and find something closer to your needs.

Comment: @user1850479 It's a buck converter as long as I am understanding the datasheet correctly. But I would need buck/boost converter, because 12VDC in, 15VDC out. But they are all optimised for PWM dimming and I can't see a simple solution to just hook up a simple DC-signal (like 0-3.3V) to adjust the output current flowing to the light bulbs.

Comment: @Dakalaom Yes sorry, you'd need to pick similar boost from their catalog.  For example, TPS61500, but there are lots of options.  A simple way to apply dimming with a 0-3.3v is to build a current divider around the current shunt resistor and then inject your own current. But that requires you to have an analog voltage, so lots of these devices make it easier by letting you control the current with a digital pin, with the duty cycle determining the how much current you get.